# Google Sheets - VLookup and date

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

My problem is that I am unable to return a value based on a specific date (eg "01/28/2022") within a Google Sheet using VLookup. I have searched the site and cant find a solution.

I have 2 columns. Column 1 contains dates (that are formulas) and Column 2 contains the numeric values that I need. Becasue the dates are formulas I am aware I need to use the DATEVALUE function but I can't figure out how.

In another part of my spreadsheet I have successfully been able to return my Column 2 values based on the same Column 1 dates using the IF function and DATEVALUE(xx)=DATE(xx,xx,xx). However for VLookup I cant get it to work.

Comment: There is not much anyone will be able to tell you when we can't see the spreadsheet. Please share a link.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Whether you choose to provide a spreadsheet or not, your question lacks detail. _Column 1 contains dates (that are formulas)_ but what is the formula? You successfully use an `IF` but what is the full formula?. `DATEVALUE` converts a date string to a date value. but where are the date strings. We **really** do want to help so would you please edit your question to describe (and provide an example of) the formula in Column A, details of the `VLOOKUP` formula that you have tried, the details of the `IF` formula. You might also consider providing sample data.

Comment: Hi. Link is here. The column 1 dates come from another sheet and are therefore formula. I want to perform a VLOOKUP on Column1 for a specific date and return the value in Column. Thanks https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ruv_Z4OYykxwq5txw5N3WhX3oKaWI0xQk5BVXdEfZpk/edit#gid=1363630354

Comment: Your spreadsheet requires a request for access. It is in your best interests to make it as easy as possible for volunteers to view your spreadsheet and consider your question. Would you please make the spreadsheet available for anyone with the link.

Comment: Apologies. Am new to Googlesheets. Accessible link:-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ruv_Z4OYykxwq5txw5N3WhX3oKaWI0xQk5BVXdEfZpk/edit?usp=sharing